# Spinner does not change but adapter does

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

I have created `Spinner` in my app and when I do something I'm changing my adapter. After the change when I open the spinner it should refresh the list of the names but it stays the same. When I check the adapter I can see that list is refreshed correctly but it doesn't shows in the spinner. Here is my code:

```
public void addItemsToSpinner(UserSettings settings) {
    List<Recipient> list = settings.getRecipients();

    Recipient selectedRecipient = settings.getSelectedRecipient();

    List<String> nicks = new ArrayList<>();

    if (selectedRecipient != null) {
        Log.d("utolsó","selected name " + selectedRecipient.getNickname());
        nicks.add(selectedRecipient.getNickname());
    }
    for (Recipient recipient: list) {
        if (selectedRecipient == null || !recipient.getNickname().equals(selectedRecipient.getNickname())) {

            nicks.add(recipient.getNickname());
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ;i<nicks.size();i++){
        Log.d("TAG","print the order = " + nicks.get(i));
    }

    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, nicks);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_recipient_chooser, container, false);
    mSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerChooser);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onRecipientSelected(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

When I the order it's correct but in the spinner it's not. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: notify adapter after adding items..dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I did in onItemSelected. Where should I do that? Before setting adapter to spinner?

Comment: when you add new items to the list you should notify your adapter.So after adding items to nicks list.

Comment: I have edited my code now you can see where do I call it. After that in the log the list's order is correct but the first object in spinner is wrong again.

Comment: are u calling addItemsToSpinner more than once...

Comment: Okay. Now when I click on the spinner the list order is right. But before I click on the spinner the first element is old. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> have you tried using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after list is changed

Comment: You should do this after you set your adapter and after you add new items to the list

Comment: I have edited my code now you can see where do I call it. After that in the log the list's order is correct but the first object in spinner is wrong again

Comment: got it .. because you are adding first item here      if (selectedRecipient != null) {
        Log.d("utolsó","selected name " + selectedRecipient.getNickname());
        nicks.add(selectedRecipient.getNickname());
    }

Comment: Okay. Now when I click on the spinner the list order is right. But before I click on the spinner the first element is old. Can you help me with this?

Comment: after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();       mSpinner.setSelection(0)  do this only after checking if new items are added to list

Comment: Then is there any way to set the spinner defult item to the same as in the spinner list? When I click on the spinner the first element of the list is not the same I can see in the default state.